# Call asp.net Webapplication From another asp.net Webapplication and Pass the whole xml data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two Webapplication Webapplication1 and Webapplication2. I am reading xml data in Webapplication1. I have to pass that data to Webapplication2 and print that data from Page_Load of  Default.aspx page of Webapplication2. How i will do this please help any one. Be sure that i am not using any type of Webservice. Actually i have to run Webapplication2 from Webapplication1 with passing data.

Comment: can you elaborate so we can help you, please ?

Comment: If you want a proper answer you need to ask a proper question. This question is not clear at all, so it's almost impossible to answer...

Answer (score 1):

Several solutions:

- Write data in a common database, and pool or set sql dependencies via service broker to know when to read the data;
- Webservice, if don't want to use that develop and ASHX Handler (ashx) and call it, it the same as developing as asps page return data, but the ASHX is lighter;
- Write files to filesystem and read from that repository;

Does any of this apply to your problem? If not, what do you want to do concretely?

Regards.

Comment: First requirement is I want to run Webapplication2 from Webapplication1 how i will do this...pls give me proper answer.

Comment: What do you mean by running webapp2 from webapp1?  If you add a web service to webapp2 then you are "running" the application when you call the web service.

Comment: @KumodSingh Oh ok, right, you can compile WebApplication2 into a DLL right, like WebApp2.dll then import this dll in the WebApp1 a can your code. Note that the methods in WebApp2 must be declared public so you can call then from WebApp2. It's this what you want right?

Comment: I Want to start the my webapplication....by this way..                            ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("http://192.168.30.87/ClientUser/Default.aspx/");
            Process.Start(sInfo);                                                                   and also want to pass data by post method that will be use to displya in Default.aspx page;

Comment: That is not very elegant... Follow my suggestion, call ProcessStartInfo("192.168.30.87/ClientUser/Default.aspx?userid=something_identifing_the_user"); Then on WebApp2 request the data from WebApp1 that you want to pass via POST and specify the userid.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
    HttpWebRequest req = null;
    HttpWebResponse rsp = null;

    string fileName = @"c:\Test.xml";
    string uri = "your second application URL with Page, where you want to get the XML Data";


    req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);

    // req.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy(); // Enable if using proxy
    req.Method = "POST"; // Post method
    req.ContentType = "text/xml"; // content type

    // Wrap the request stream with a text-based writer
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());

    // Write the XML text into the stream
    writer.WriteLine(GetTextFromXMLFile(fileName));
    writer.Close();

    // Send the data to the webserver
    rsp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

    Stream Answer = rsp.GetResponseStream();
     //_Answer = new StreamReader(Answer);
    XmlTextReader _Answer = new XmlTextReader(Answer);
```

Read the XML Data Second web application page

```
Page.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        // Read XML posted via HTTP
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Page.Request.InputStream);
        string xmlData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        sw.Write(xmlData);
        sw.Close();
```